# Select customers only got red cars in mysql (not red and green both )

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables customer,car customer_has_car .I want to get the customers who has got only red cars using given scenario. Not red and green both.

> My tables information given below:

[image]

> Output should be :

Jhon ,
Ann

Any suggestion please...

Comment: only 1 car and it is red? or red and plaid is ok?

Comment: Jhon has a blue and a red car, therefore Jhon should not be in the expected result if this statement is true: "I want to get the customers who has got only red cars"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MAX(color) = the MIN(color) then there is only one value for color, and you do not need to specify any other color in the query.

```
SELECT
      c.cus_id
    , c.cus_name
    , c.tel
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_has_car chc
      ON c.cus_id = chc.cus_id
INNER JOIN car
      ON chc.id_car = car.id_car
GROUP BY c.cus_id
       , c.cus_name
       , c.tel
HAVING MIN(car.color) = 'red'
AND MAX(car.color) = 'red'
;
```

Comment: I am not sure you thought about the possibility that there might be other colors as well, like blue. Look at the example, where jhon has a blue car and is still in the expected result set...

Comment: With respect, this is precisely my point, because you can have a myriad of colours any solution that is based on NOT 'green' or NOT IN ('green','blue') is unmanageable. Using MIN/MAX solves this problem because for the MIN to be equal to the MAX there can ONLY be ONE VALUE (in this case 'red')

Comment: oh, sorry I see your point. I think the question is flawed. In the opening line it states: "I want to get the customers who has got only red cars" and that is what my suggestion aims to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

### Schema:

```
create table customer
(   cus_id int not null,
    cus_name varchar(20) not null,
    tel varchar(20) not null
);

create table car
(   id_car int not null,
    car_name varchar(20) not null,
    `year` int not null,
    color varchar(20) not null
);

create table customer_has_car
(   cus_id int not null,
    id_car int not null,
    `date` date not null
);

insert car (id_car,car_name,`year`,color) values (1,'corolla',2012,'red');
insert car (id_car,car_name,`year`,color) values (2,'corolla',2013,'blue');
insert car (id_car,car_name,`year`,color) values (3,'corolla',2014,'red');
insert car (id_car,car_name,`year`,color) values (4,'corolla',2003,'green');

insert customer(cus_id,cus_name,tel) values (1,'jhon','012345');
insert customer(cus_id,cus_name,tel) values (2,'Ann','875646');
insert customer(cus_id,cus_name,tel) values (3,'Sam','446363');
insert customer(cus_id,cus_name,tel) values (4,'Cristina','356561');

insert customer_has_car(cus_id,id_car,date) values (1,1,'2015-01-08');
insert customer_has_car(cus_id,id_car,date) values (1,2,'2015-07-08');
insert customer_has_car(cus_id,id_car,date) values (2,1,'2015-08-08');
insert customer_has_car(cus_id,id_car,date) values (3,4,'2015-09-08');
insert customer_has_car(cus_id,id_car,date) values (4,3,'2015-10-08');
insert customer_has_car(cus_id,id_car,date) values (4,4,'2015-11-08');
```

### Query:

```
-- has red cars but not green:
select cus_id,cus_name,tel
from ( select c.cus_id,c.cus_name,c.tel,group_concat(car.color) as colors
    from customer c
    join customer_has_car chc
    on chc.cus_id=c.cus_id
    join car
    on car.id_car=chc.id_car
    group by c.cus_id,c.cus_name) inr
where find_in_set('green',colors)=0 and find_in_set('red',colors)>0;

+--------+----------+--------+
| cus_id | cus_name | tel    |
+--------+----------+--------+
|      1 | jhon     | 012345 |
|      2 | Ann      | 875646 |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer.cus_id, customer.cus_name, customer.tel
from customer
where 
exists (select 1
        from customer_has_car
        where id_car in (select id_car
                         from car
                         where color = 'red') and customer_has_car.cus_id = customer.cus_id) and
not exists (select 1
            from customer_has_car
            where id_car in (select id_car
                             from car
                             where color = 'green') and customer_has_car.cus_id = customer.cus_id)
```

Whenever you need to solve a problem like this, you need to think about the simplest parts at first. First, you need to think about how can you find the red cars and the green cars. Try to write those queries down. When you have this result, then integrate it into the bigger question of how do you need to filter customer_has_car with it. Then, write the large select and add the additional filters.